# How to filter nested object array in Angular/Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, filter

I have the following object array

```
rules = [
  {
    ID: "581944a9-2f9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
    RequestID: "75430ba1-2c9c-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
    Number: 2,
    Description: "",
    Applicable: true,
    Result: false,
    cfRequestDocumentComparison: [
      {
        ID: "5fbdd6d4-2f9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        RuleID: "581944a9-2f9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        SourceDocumentID: "2619f2f8-2e9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        DestinationDocumentID: null,
        SourceValue: "ΜΗΝΑΣ",
        DestinationValue: "ΜΗΝΑΣ",
        SourceFieldName: "Id.Name",
        DestinationFieldName: "Customer.Name",
        FieldDescription: "",
        Result: true,
        SuccessRate: 100,
      },
      {
        ID: "dd87a7ed-2f9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        RuleID: "581944a9-2f9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        SourceDocumentID: "2719f2f8-2e9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        DestinationDocumentID: null,
        SourceValue: "",
        DestinationValue: "ΛΕΜΟΝΗΣ",
        SourceFieldName: "Id.LastName",
        DestinationFieldName: "Customer.Lastname",
        FieldDescription: "",
        Result: false,
        SuccessRate: 0,
      },
      {
        ID: "de87a7ed-2f9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        RuleID: "581944a9-2f9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        SourceDocumentID: "2719f2f8-2e9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        DestinationDocumentID: null,
        SourceValue: "",
        DestinationValue: "",
        SourceFieldName: "Id.Number",
        DestinationFieldName: "Customer.PoliceId",
        FieldDescription: "",
        Result: false,
        SuccessRate: 0,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    ID: "df87a7ed-2f9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
    RequestID: "75430ba1-2c9c-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
    Number: 3,
    Description: "",
    Applicable: true,
    Result: true,
    cfRequestDocumentComparison: [
      {
        ID: "e087a7ed-2f9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        RuleID: "df87a7ed-2f9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        SourceDocumentID: "2619f2f8-2e9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        DestinationDocumentID: null,
        SourceValue: "070732580",
        DestinationValue: "070732580",
        SourceFieldName: "Customer.AFM",
        DestinationFieldName: "Customer.AFM",
        FieldDescription: "",
        Result: true,
        SuccessRate: 100,
      },
      {
        ID: "e187a7ed-2f9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        RuleID: "df87a7ed-2f9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        SourceDocumentID: "2619f2f8-2e9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        DestinationDocumentID: null,
        SourceValue: "ΛΕΜΟΝΗΣ",
        DestinationValue: "ΛΕΜΟΝΗΣ",
        SourceFieldName: "Customer.Lastname",
        DestinationFieldName: "Customer.Lastname",
        FieldDescription: "",
        Result: true,
        SuccessRate: 100,
      },
      {
        ID: "e287a7ed-2f9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        RuleID: "df87a7ed-2f9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        SourceDocumentID: "2619f2f8-2e9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        DestinationDocumentID: null,
        SourceValue: "6972747462",
        DestinationValue: "6972747462",
        SourceFieldName: "Customer.MobilePhone",
        DestinationFieldName: "Customer.MobilePhone",
        FieldDescription: "",
        Result: true,
        SuccessRate: 100,
      },
      {
        ID: "e387a7ed-2f9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        RuleID: "df87a7ed-2f9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        SourceDocumentID: "2619f2f8-2e9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        DestinationDocumentID: null,
        SourceValue: "ΜΗΝΑΣ",
        DestinationValue: "ΜΗΝΑΣ",
        SourceFieldName: "Customer.Name",
        DestinationFieldName: "Customer.Name",
        FieldDescription: "",
        Result: true,
        SuccessRate: 100,
      },
      {
        ID: "e487a7ed-2f9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        RuleID: "df87a7ed-2f9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        SourceDocumentID: "2619f2f8-2e9d-eb11-8439-d46a6a4c0be8",
        DestinationDocumentID: null,
        SourceValue: "+302421024665",
        DestinationValue: "+302421024665",
        SourceFieldName: "Customer.Phone",
        DestinationFieldName: "Customer.Phone",
        FieldDescription: "",
        Result: true,
        SuccessRate: 100,
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

I would like to implement a filtering functionality by fields `SourceDocumentID` and `DestinationDocumentID` of object array `cfRequestDocumentComparison` without changing the actual array. I tried

```
public filterByDocumentPair(documentPair: {
  sourceDocID: string,
  destinationDocID: string,
  sourceDocName: string,
  destinationDocName: string,
}) {
  this.rules = this.rules.filter(
    (rule: cfRequestRule) =>
      (rule.cfRequestDocumentComparison = rule.cfRequestDocumentComparison.filter(
        (comparison: cfRequestDocumentComparison) =>
          comparison.SourceDocumentID === documentPair.sourceDocID &&
          comparison.DestinationDocumentID === documentPair.destinationDocID
      ))
  );
}
```

but `rule.cfRequestDocumentComparison =` changes the actual array and, as a result, cannot retrieve all the `cfRequestDocumentComparison` items after the first filtering in order to filter again correctly.

How can I achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: @Ben Thank you for the code formatting. How can I 
run code through formatter so that I do that for every future question?

Comment: My editor is configured to automatically format the code on save, so when I see posts like yours, I tend to just copy the code into the editor and press save. It rather depends what editor you are using, but most modern editors will have a similar plugin or functionality. If its more than a few symbols, I'd encourage you to write your code in the editor first and copy it into SO. An alternative might be to look for web based code formatters for JavaScript/TypeScript